# Accidentally deleted urllib3 from macOS

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I've accidentally deleted/removed the package urllib3 from my python and now when I open terminal, I get this error message.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 109, in main
    from ..exceptions import ExceptionHandler
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .common.url import maybe_unquote
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/url.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import LocationParseError
ImportError: No module named urllib3.exceptions
```

How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I even reinstalled the OS and nothing has changed.!!
Thanks

Comment: `conda install urllib3`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried pip installing it again:

pip install urllib3

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after numerous trial and error. Taking a closer look, the problem was with anaconda2. **So I deleted the entire folder anaconda2 and reinstalled anaconda python 2.7**.

Issue is solved.